# Setting nested array in Laravel collection class

Tags: php, laravel, overloading

Consider the following Laravel snippet:

```
$var = collect(['foo' => []]);
$var['foo']['x'] = 2;
```

It cause `Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect in C:/…/file.php` notice. What is it all about?

Answer (score 4):

I know I have come across this problem before and I can tell you it is not Laravel related. This problem applies to any class that implements PHP's `ArrayAccess` interface. Let me explain.

If you take a look at PHP's [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, you will see the following method:

```
abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
```

Which, a common definition for this method would be something like:

```
public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
}
```

[Laravel's `Collection` object](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) implements this `ArrayAccess` interface and it allows you to access objects as arrays.

So, what happens when you use the `[]` operator on this object? The `offsetGet` method is called and it returns an array, but not a *reference* to that array. So any changes you make will be made into space, since the returned array does not reference the actual array in the object. You can understand this more by looking into the `ArrayAccess` interface yourself, but what really matters is the solution.

```
$var = collect(['foo' => []]);

$temp = $var['foo'];
$temp['x'] = 2;

$var['foo'] = $temp;
```